# android studio mapview show black

Tags: rendering, android-mapview

i have a probleme using mapview for android studio when i update to last version both android and sdk

im using  this conf in gradle

compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        renderscriptTargetApi 21 
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0

the map cannot be rendered and it shown black in startup . pls can any body help me !!!

- **# com.esri.arcgisruntime.mapping.view.MapView** (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
  Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE.
  If this is an unexpected error you can also try to build the project, then manually refresh the layout.  Exception Details 
  java.lang.VerifyError: # **Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 19** Exception Details: 
  Location: 
  com/esri/arcgisruntime/mapping/view/GeoView. (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V @10: ifeq Reason: Expected stackmap frame at this location. Bytecode: 0x0000000: 2a2b 2cb7 001d 2ab6 0021 9900 092a 01b5 0x0000010: 0023 b1b1    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Class.java:-2)   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)   at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3075)   at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:858)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:861)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:834)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)